# How many is too many for create dispatch_queues in GCD (grand central dispatch)?

Tags: multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

There is a wonderful article about a lightweight notification system built in Swift, by Mike Ash: (https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-01-23-lets-build-swift-notifications.html).

The basic idea is you create objects that you can "listen" to i.e. invoke a callback on when there is some state change.  To make it thread-safe, each object created holds its own dispatch_queue.  The dispatch_queue is simply used to gate critical sections:

```
dispatch_sync(self.myQueue) {
    // modify critical state in self
}
```

and moreover it likely won't be in high contention.  I was kind of struck by the fact that *every* single object you create that can be listened to makes its own dispatch queue, just for the purposes of locking a few lines of code.

One poster suggested an OS_SPINLOCK would be faster and cheaper; maybe, but it would certainly use a lot less space.

If my program creates hundreds or thousands (or even tens of thousands of objects) should I worry about creating so many dispatch queues?    Probably most won't ever even be listened to, but some might.

It certainly makes sense that two objects not block each other, i.e. have separate locks, and normally I wouldn't think twice about embedding, say, a pthread_mutex in each object, but an entire dispatch queue?  is that really ok?

Comment: just for completeness these should be linked, even though @Hamish 's answer is much better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291636/how-many-dispatch-queues-should-one-make-less-is-better-or-more-is-better#comment35661939_23293526

Answer (score 22):

[Well, the documentation on Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079) is fairly vague about the inner workings & the exact costs of dispatch queues, however it does state that:

> GCD provides and manages FIFO queues to which your application can submit tasks in the form of block objects. **Blocks submitted to dispatch queues are executed on a pool of threads fully managed by the system.**

So, it sounds like queues are no more than an interface for queueing blocks through a thread pool, and therefore have no/minimal impact on performance when idle.

[The conceptual documentation also states that:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1)

> You can create as many serial queues as you need

Which definitely sounds like there's almost a trivial cost with creating serial a dispatch queue, and leaving it idle.

Furthermore, I decided to test creating 10,000 serial and concurrent dispatch queues on an app with some Open GL content, and didn't find that the performance was impacted in any way, the FPS remained the same, and it only utilised an extra 4MB of RAM (~400 bytes for a single queue).

In terms of using an OS_SPINLOCK instead of dispatch queues, Apple is *very* clear in it's documentation about [migrating away threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1) that GCD is more efficient than using standard locks (at least in contended cases).

> Replacing your lock-based code with queues **eliminates many of the penalties associated with locks** and also simplifies your remaining code. Instead of using a lock to protect a shared resource, you can instead create a queue to serialize the tasks that access that resource. **Queues do not impose the same penalties as locks.** For example, queueing a task does not require trapping into the kernel to acquire a mutex.

Although it's also worth noting that you can always release a queue if you're not using it and re-create it later when it needs using again, if you are concerned about memory.

---

### TL;DR

Dispatch queues are the way to go. You don't need to worry too much about creating lots of queues and not using them, and they're certainly more efficient than locks.

**Edit:** You actually found that a spinlock is faster in un-contended situations, so you'll probably want to use that for this!

Comment: I found some time to do a benchmark.  I agree that in the contested case, a spinlock is a bad idea.  In the uncontested case, I'm getting a spinlock costing about 80 nanoseconds, while using dispatch_sync to a queue costs around 500 nanoseconds.    This is on the latest dual-core mac-mini; probably a good bit faster on  my laptop.

 400 bytes for a queue certainly seems pretty reasonable as well.  thanks for your input!

Comment: ah, that is interesting. Good to know!

Comment: Oops:  Some part of that 500 nanoseconds is also measuring the time to form the closure and then call it.   So a spinlock would still be faster, but it's really because with a spinlock you can avoid forming a closure and then calling it.  If you actually form the closure and pass it to a function which locks a spinlock, invokes the closure, and unlocks the spinlock, it is pretty much the exact same time as using a dispatch queue.  (Which leads me to think that in the common case that is probably what a dispatch queue is doing.)

Comment: OSSpinLock is deprecated according to the header OSSpinLockDeprecated.h. Also It's supposedly usafe. The header says "These interfaces should no longer be used, particularily in situations where threads of differing priorities may contend on the same spinlock."

Comment: Its not true that you can create as many serial queues as you want. The documentation mentions that:

"You can create any number of serial queues for your application but should avoid creating large numbers of serial queues solely as a means to execute as many tasks simultaneously as you can."

Your answer gives incomplete information and is misguiding people.

Comment: Ankit: This comment in the document is more about how you use dispatch queues than how many you create. Even if you can create 10,000 queues, it's not recommended to use them to send 10,000 blocks at once. I don't think Hamish's answer is misguiding in any way: for the OP's purpose, this is still a very valid use.